# Add one button (as subview) to multiple UIViews

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have a UIButton and I want to add it to multiple UIViews. Later on - I want to remove it from one of the superviews. I am trying it the following way but when I pass the removeFromSuperview message to the button, it gets removed from both the views:

```
[viewOverlay addSubview:myButton];
[viewButtons addSubview:myButton];
```

Afterwards I want it to be removed from the viewOverlay only.

```
[myButton removeFromSuperview];
```

and this causes the button removed from both the views. Any idea how can I achieve this???

Obaid

Comment: you **cannot** do it, every `UIView` subclass (as the `UIButton`) has **only one** superview at same time, no more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I pass the removeFromSuperview message to the button, it gets
>   removed from both the views

It might look that way, but `myButton` was removed from `viewOverlay` when you added it to `viewButtons`. From the documentation for `-addSubview:`:

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and
>   that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.

The only correct solution here is to create two buttons and add one to each of `viewOverlay` and `viewButtons`. The two buttons can look the same, have the same target, and perform the same action, so they'll look like the "same" button from the user's perspective. But a view can only have one superview at a time. I mean that literally: every view has a `superview` pointer that points to the view that contains it, and that point can obviously only point to one object at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add one view to multiple views at the same time. In this case firstly added view will be removed and added for second. To achieve this you need to create one more instance or copy existed.

From [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) -

> A parent view may contain any number of subviews but each subview has
>   only one superview, which is responsible for positioning its subviews
>   appropriately.